# Undefined text at click event on <li><p>text</p></li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fix it... I really don't know why this is not working.

I have some `<ul>` where some `<li>` are inserted by keyUp/keydown events (tipical AJAX searcher) so, this `<li>` represents the DDBB matches now.

I would like to so some code after click in some `<li>` (this) and then get the text inside it (because I will use it to render another URL using this text as a parameter)... I don't know why I got undefined text 24/7.

Here is a demo : http://codepen.io/tureey/pen/VaagyY

```js
// Redirije a la URL pertinente para cargar la información de esa búsqueda
$('#searcher-ajax li').click(function() {
  alert("enter");
  var a = $(this).children('div').children('p').innerHTML;
  alert(a);
});
```

```css
#searcher {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
#searcher-ajax {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#searcher-ajax li.searcher-ajax-element {
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #040507 url("/static/img/bg-bar.jpg") repeat 50% 0;
}
#searcher-ajax li.searcher-ajax-element div {
  text-align: left;
}
#searcher-ajax li.searcher-ajax-element div img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  max-width: 30px;
  max-height: 30px;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
#searcher-ajax li.searcher-ajax-element div p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
#searcher-ajax li.searcher-ajax-element:hover,
#searcher-ajax li.searcher-ajax-element:active,
#searcher-ajax li.searcher-ajax-element:focus {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: black;
  background-image: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul id="searcher-ajax">
  <li class="searcher-ajax-element">
    <div class="searcher-ajax-element-div">
      <p>text1</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="searcher-ajax-element">
    <div class="searcher-ajax-element-div">
      <p>text2</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="searcher-ajax-element">
    <div class="searcher-ajax-element-div">
      <p>text3</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Thanks for help.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery function [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of `children`, because element you want to find (`p`) is not a direct child of your context (`li`).

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaagdL

How you could have fixed it sooner: do not presume your code works until the last step. You could have just checked and seen that `$(this).children('p')` already returns empty collection (not what you expected).

Comment: Your JS is missing the final `});` :)

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is the path you are trying to find.

You need to do:

```
var a = $(this).children('div').children('p')[0].innerHTML
```